# Simple Binding won't work/update C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, textblock

Update at bottom.

---

I think my mistake is a very simple one, but I don't know what to try else.

I have View which has a TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="aCalories" 
           Text="{Binding Path= aCalories, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           Grid.Row="5" 
           Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Foreground="#2d3b53" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

After doing some stuff, like adding Calories of different items "**aColories**" should update after the changes were made. But "**aColories**" stays 0. 
Thanks to Breakpoints I see that **"_acalories"** gets values but it seems like they don't get passed to my View.

aClories in my ViewModel:

```
namespace FoodsLib.ViewModel

{
  public class ViewModelTagesBedarfWindow : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged 
  {

    public ViewModelTagesBedarfWindow(Repository repository, ModelPersone logedPers) : base(repository)
    {
        LoginPerson = logedPers;
    }

 private double _acalories;
 public double aCalories
 {
     get 
     { 
         return _acalories; 
     }
     set 
     {
         if (_acalories != value)
         {
             _acalories = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("aCalories");
         }
     }

 // my OnPropertyChanged
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
 {
     PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
 }
 }
```

And my .xaml.cs

```
public ViewModelTagesBedarfWindow MyViewModel { get; set; }
//ViewModelFrdg _viewModel;
public TagesBedarfWindow(ModelPersone logedPerson)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyViewModel = new ViewModelTagesBedarfWindow(new Repository(), logedPerson);
    this.DataContext = MyViewModel;

    logedPers = logedPerson;

}
```

I would like to be able to get values and that the values change automatic.

For example:
Another "TextBlock" Binds to this and (semi) works.
But this also doesn't updated after a change was made.

```
public double aSatFat
    {
        get 
        { 
           return LoginPerson.RDASatFat; 
        }
        set
        {
            _asatFat = LoginPerson.RDASatFat;
            OnPropertyChanged("aSatFat");

        }
    }
```

---

It seems like it was as simple as I thought.

The Binding was correct and my DataContext was set alright, but with many Models I confused 2 different "calories" from two different Models.
One named:"**_acalories**" the other "**RDACalories**".

I understand the downvote, because my mistake is a simple one and noone benefits from the answer.

Comment: Do you have any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `ViewModel` class

Comment: No Binding errors for this problem, sadly.
Edit: Yes is implemented.

Comment: Just incase you aren't understanding @Jace, make sure ViewModelTagesBedarfWindow  extends INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: See changes in Question.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding seems to be correct and code is perfect too. 
The issue seems to be with this code :

```
MyViewModel = new ViewModelTagesBedarfWindow(new Repository(), logedPerson);
this.DataContext = MyViewModel;
```

The dataContext is not being set. Put a break point at this position and check whether the dataContext is being set properly.

```
public TagesBedarfWindow(ModelPersone logedPerson)
```

Also you need a default constructor, means a constructor which doesn't take any parameter. So the above constructor is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but seems like it works fine without a default constructor (somehow). The mistake was a simple one.

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: I confused two properties (both for "calories") of two different models. I gave 1 property the value and tried to display another property which never had any values. I was a bit tired at 4.am...

Comment: I manualy set (for example) _asatfat with RDASatFat and RDASatFat was never set with any value.